# R LSA LSAFUN enconding problems

Tags: r, encoding, linguistics, lsa

I would like to use the `genericSummary` function from package `LSAfun`. Here´s a german sample text.

```
library("LSAfun")
text = " Gegen die Firma wurde während der letzten Woche ein Zwangsvollstreckungsverfahren eingeleitet. Darüber witzeln die Konkurrenten."
```

The encoding of my texts is "UTF-8". Actually, the encoding of this sample text is "latin1". Therefore I converted to utf8

```
text = enc2utf8(text)
```

When I call

```
genericSummary(text, k=2)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  [lsa] - could not open file C:\Users\MA\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcRnDPw\file16c81a35d06/sentence1.txt due to encoding problems of the file.
```

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

had the same problem. It seems that the special characters like 'ü' and 'ä' are the cause here.
By replacing them with 'ue' and 'ae' the coding will work.

try this:
genericSummary(text,k=2, language="german", breakdown=T)

the breakdown option will do the job, see also R-help to this function.

Kind regards,
Michael.